# How to import .mdd files?

Tags: animation, import, file-format

In the older versions you used to import the .obj file, select it then *File* > *Import* and select the .mdd file.
In the 2.73 version I don't see that option anymore. Does anyone know how to import .mdd files into Blender with the newer version?

Comment: I saw some people are using this add on but it doesn't have an option for Mac users.
 https://github.com/sugiany/blender_mmd_tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of directly importing an `.mdd` file you may want to use a [mesh cache modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/modify/mesh_cache.html).

A mesh cache modifier can read `.mdd` and `.pc2` files and then replaces the objects mesh data with the files mesh for a given frame. Modifier properties allow adjustments for how the animation is played back.

[image]

Comment: Problem with this is of course, that you cannot apply corrections, i.e. shape keys, on top of the modifier.  So this solution is not so useful if you want to make loops involving cloth.

Answer (score 4):

If the .mdd option for importing isn't available, load the add-on in User Preferences:

File >> User Preferences >> Add-ons >> Import-Export: NewTek MDD format (Enable the add-on)

Comment: No where online, google searches, have any details for how to EXPORT from Blender in MDD, until I found your answer here. THANK YOU.